# How to load unicode string into json in Python?

Tags: python, json, unicode, tarfile

I am trying to read file from a compressed file and convert data into json/ dictionary. But there is unicode issue that I have been struggling for a while. Can anyone help ?

```
exfile_obj = tar.extractfile(member)
data = exfile_obj.read()
print(type(data)) ## shows str
print(data)  ## it is something like: "{u'building': False, u'displayName': u'Tam\\xe1s Kosztol\\xe1nczi', u'changeSet': {u'items': u'comment'}}"
json_obj = json.loads(data) # it is a unicode object.
```

Answer (score 9):

That data is a string representation of a Python dictionary. You can convert it to a dictionary using `ast.literal_eval`, and you can convert that dict to a JSON string using `json.dumps`.

```
import ast
import json

src = "{u'building': False, u'displayName': u'Tam\\xe1s Kosztol\\xe1nczi', u'changeSet': {u'items': u'comment'}}"
data = ast.literal_eval(src)
print(data)
j = json.dumps(data)
print(j)
```

**output**

```
{'building': False, 'displayName': 'Tamás Kosztolánczi', 'changeSet': {'items': 'comment'}}
{"building": false, "displayName": "Tam\u00e1s Kosztol\u00e1nczi", "changeSet": {"items": "comment"}}
```

Comment: Your example returns a dict (data = ast.literal_eval(src)). But it is strange that it did not return as I expected when I modified my code accordingly. It returned a str still. My changed codes are :  exfile_obj = tar.extractfile(member)
        data = exfile_obj.read()
        print(type(data))
        json_obj = ast.literal_eval(data)
        print(type(json_obj)) ## it is a str

Comment: What else I found was that when ast.literal_eval gets input from file using with open("example.json") as file: src = f.read() ( NOT from variable) it returns str. But if ast.literal_eval gets input from variable, it returns a dict.

Comment: When I read from file. The data look like this: '"{u\'building\': False, u\'displayName\': u\'Tam\\\\xe1s Kosztol\\\\xe1nczi\', u\'changeSet\': {u\'items\': u\'comment\'}}"\n' @PM 2Ring

Comment: I think I found the reason. The json file is not formatted properly. It is a str type not a json type. Once quotes are removed from the file, this solution worked. thanks.